# Two wireless routers on one internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

At the place I live I believe the shared wireless router has been compromised in some way or has some type of virus. As a work around I have connected my own securely configured wireless router running DD-WRT firmware to the same internet switch. Both routers have different SSIDs and passwords and both are using DHCP to get their IPs.

It seems that when I am using my DD-WRT router and on the internet, it is causing intermittent page loading problems on the other wireless connection, so there is some conflict happening between the two routers at the switch. It is only affecting the other router though as the page loading on my DD-WRT router always works great.

Is there a simple setting I can enable in my DD-WRT router to fix the conflict? What would be the easiest way for me to configure on my end so the two routers work in harmony, yet remain separate as they are now?

Comment: Looks like this might be more suitable for [su].

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should certainly be broadcasting on different wireless channels for starters and it probably wouldn't be a bad idea to use a unique IP range for the built in DHCP server.